# WCF - Is it possible to listen back from a Thread and do something in a WCF Service which has already sent response?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf

I have a WCF service in which I am starting a Thread which does a batch file process (Thread invokes a third party DLL where I can not change anything). It is just starting the thread and sending the response back that Thread has been started.

Before calling the thread the C# code creates a temp folder to be used by the external dll. Which is required to be deleted once the thread operation is completed. Now as the service call has already responded I think it doesn't exist.

So my question is can I listen back from that Thread? If yes then where? because service instance might not exist that time (though it is not required, I just need to delete the temp folder).

Comment: So basically you want to wait until the temp folder got deleted before responding to the service call?

Comment: Why not to use async operations? You can create a `Task` on the server side and send it back as result.

Comment: @tia No I need to respond in service call just after starting the thread. But temp folder need be deleted when thread is complete.

Comment: @YohDeadfall Asynch Task can respond and be still active to complete the delete operation while its completed?

Comment: Yes, `Task` can do the job. The problem is that your `Task`s might get aborted when you stop server, and there is no way to gracefully wait for them to finish before. If you are running your service on ASP.NET, QueueBackgroundWorkItem might be a good solution. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/04/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-long-background-process-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: A returned `Task` will behave like a standard task. It will be completed only when the external method ends and the temp directory is removed. See [Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701(v=vs.110).aspx).